# Generate all numbers from 1- 20 using 5,10,15,20 using operators *,/,+,-,^

Tags: puzzle

I have to make all the numbers from 1-20 using the operators *,/,+,-,^ and the numbers 5,10,15,20.

Specifically, how I make 14 and 16?

Edit:
Every number has to be used and only once. Parentheses are allowed. Operators can be used to any amount as required.

Comment: do you have to use all the numbers and operators?

Comment: Perhaps it'd be helpful if we could see a few examples - say 1-10. In addition, I presume we can't use numbers/operators more than once? Are parentheses allowed?

Comment: Every number has to be used and only once. Parentheses are allowed. Operators can be used to any amount as required

Comment: In addition, some context may be helpful - is this a challenge posed to you by someone? If so, presumably it can definitely be done?

Comment: @Shuri2060 It's a challenge given by a co worker. The original challenge was to select any 4 numbers from 1-20 and make all numbers from 1-20. I selected 5,10,15,20. I've gotten 18 numbers till now. Just left with 16 and 14

Comment: I see - in which case it may very well be impossible.

Comment: must also make use of $15$

Comment: how did you get $18$ out of curiosity?

Comment: @Dando18 [5-(20/10)]+15

Comment: _"Operators can be used to any amount as required."_ --> is that allowed: 14= (5 * 10 - 20 - 15)-- and 16= (5 * 10 - 20 - 15)++ ?

Comment: @fonfonx You'd be able to make any number with the ++ and -- operators trivially. They are different from + and -, and are used in programming.

Comment: @Shuri2060 sure I was just founding the fact that you can use any amout of operators funny

Comment: I've a feeling that it's impossible. Showing it may be quite hard - out of interest how many cases will we have to go through with brute force?

Comment: I'm trying to formulate some sketch on how to show impossibility.

Comment: I suppose powering is out, since for $14$, even if you have the square root power, there is no way you can get to $196$ with the rest. Hence we must rely on $+,-,/,*$

Answer (score 4):

It's simply impossible. Proof: *brute force*

*c++* code (**Edit:** sorry for the bump, but I've improved greatly the code I included to generalize operations [now accounts for exponents], so I can definitively say there is no way to make 14 and 16 based on a brute force search):

```
typedef int Digit;

constexpr Digit numDigits{4};
constexpr Digit target{24};

typedef float (*Operator)(float, float);
typedef std::map<char, Operator> Operators;

// operators
float add(float a, float b) {return a+b;}
float subtract(float a, float b) {return a-b;}
float multiply(float a, float b) {return a*b;}
float divide(float a, float b) {return a/b;}
float power(float a, float b) {return powf(a,b);}

const Operators operators = {{'+', add}, {'-', subtract}, {'*', multiply}, {'/', divide}, {'^', power}};
const std::map<Operator, char> operators_inverse = flip_map(operators);  // new map with keys and values swapped

typedef std::array<Digit, numDigits> digits;
digits d;

void print_solution(const std::array<Digit, numDigits>& nums, std::vector<char> &ops) {
    std::string accum (numDigits-2, '(');
    for(unsigned i=0; i<numDigits-1; ++i) {
        accum += std::to_string(nums[i]);
        if (i!=0) accum += ')';
        accum += std::string(&ops[i], 1);
    }
    accum += std::to_string(nums[numDigits-1]);
    printf("%s\n",accum.c_str());
}

int main() {

    d = {3,6,10, 4};

    if(std::accumulate(d.begin(), d.end(), 0) == target) {
        std::vector<char> v(numDigits-1,'+');
        print_solution(d, v);
    }
    if(std::accumulate(d.begin(), d.end(), 1, multiply) == target) {
        std::vector<char> v(numDigits-1,'*');
        print_solution(d, v);
    }

    auto keys = map_keys(operators);   // vector of map keys
    auto ops = map_values(operators);  // vector of map values
    std::sort(d.begin(), d.end());
    std::sort(ops.begin(), ops.end());
    do {
        do{
            float last = ops[0](d[0], d[1]);   // init with inner-most value

            for(unsigned i=1; i<numDigits-1; ++i) {  // - 2 cause there are |d|-1 operators
                last = ops[i](d[i+1], last);
            }

            if(last == target) {
                std::vector<char> v;
                for(Operator o : ops) {
                    v.push_back(operators_inverse.at(o));
                }
                print_solution(d, v);
            }
        } while (std::next_permutation(d.begin(), d.end()));
    } while (std::next_permutation(ops.begin(), ops.end()));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is nice.  Do you have some output as far as the unique values returned by this code between say 1 and 100?

Comment: I think it's best to include powers - you could still have (.^.)+(.^.), for example (although I agree that it's probably still impossible).

Comment: @Shuri2060 actually I decided not to include them based off of the comment _and_ the fact that I lazily hardcoded in operator combinations so incorporating powers would greatly increase the size of the code. I'm working on a more general solution rn in mathematica and I'll make sure to account for powers.

Comment: Nice use of `std::next_permutation`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another program that evaluates all the well-formed RPN (Reverse Polish Notation) strings made up with numbers $\{5,10,15,20\}$ and operators $\{+,*,-,/,\hat{}\}$.

```
""" Make numbers in range(1,21) out of {5, 10, 15, 20} with {+ - * / ^}.
    Each number must be used exactly once.
    The program forms RPN strings and evaluates them, reporting those that
    produce integers in the range from 1 to 20 (included).
"""

from __future__ import print_function

def eval_rpn(s):
    """ Evaluates RPN string. """
    global rcnt, ucnt
    es = []
    for x in s:
        if x in numbers:
            es.append(float(x))
        else:
            v2 = es.pop()
            v1 = es.pop()
            if x == '+':
                es.append(v1+v2)
            elif x == '*':
                es.append(v1*v2)
            elif x == '-':
                es.append(v1-v2)
            elif x == '/':
                if v1 % v2 != 0:
                    raise ValueError
                es.append(v1/v2)
            elif x == '^':
                es.append(v1**v2)
            else:
                raise RuntimeError()
    if len(es) != 1:
        raise RuntimeError()
    value = es[0]
    if value in range(1,21):
        rcnt += 1
        print(', '.join(s), '=', value)
        if not value in sample:
            sample[value] = s
    if value in [14, 16]:
        ucnt += 1
        print('******** whoa! ********')

def pick_cand_tk(s, nums):
    """ Picks all tokens that may be used to extend RPN string. """
    cand = []
    for n in numbers:
        if not n in s:
            cand.append(n)
    if 2*nums - len(s) > 1:
        cand.extend(['+', '*', '-', '/', '^'])
    return cand

def rpn_recur(s,nums):
    """ Recursively construct well-formed RPN strings. """
    global tcnt
    if len(s) == 7:
        try:
            eval_rpn(s)
        except (OverflowError, ZeroDivisionError, ValueError):
            pass
        tcnt += 1
    else:
        for c in pick_cand_tk(s, nums):
            rpn_recur(s + [c], nums + (c in numbers))


numbers = ['5', '10', '15', '20']
tcnt = 0 # total number of leaves
rcnt = 0 # number of leaves whose evaluation is in range(1,21)
ucnt = 0 # number of unexpected values
sample = {}
rpn_recur([], 0)

print('leaves: total =', tcnt, ' in-range =', rcnt, ' unxepected =', ucnt)
for k in sample:
    print(int(k), '->', ', '.join(sample[k]))
```

The program examines 15000 RPN strings, finds that than 852 evaluate to an integer between 1 and 20, also finds that no string evaluates to either 14 or 16, and finally prints examples of how to obtain the other numbers in the range.

Computations are carried out with integer values throughout.  This excludes results like $(20/5)^{15/10} = 8$.  To include them, one comments out the check on the $0$ remainder in `eval_rpn`.  In any case, $14$ and $16$ remain off limits.